# Rails 3.2. Create tests for existing model. Scaffold error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, testing, scaffolding

I would like to generate tests (Test::Unit) for existing model using rails-3.2 scaffolding.

I've tried several commands and have got the following mistake:

```
  invoke  active_record

  The name 'MyModel' is either already used in your application or reserved by         
  Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run this generator again.
```

I have used the following commands and result was the same:

```
rails g scaffold MyModel --skip
rails g scaffold MyModel -s
rails g scaffold MyModel -t -s
```

I also have tried to use gem [schema_to_scaffold](http://rubydoc.info/gems/schema_to_scaffold/0.4.2/frames) to point all the MyModel fields for scaffold but it gives no result.

```
rails generate scaffold MyModel fio:string #..all fields of my model..# -s
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should work with -s option